# UITableView value?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can I assign a value to a cell in a UITableView?

So the label should display the normal label text but the value should be passed into a variable.

For example:

Label Text: Option one (what is displayed to the user)

Value: o_1 (what is passed to the variable)

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: yes that is possible it is just simple as we pass a Dictionary or array on click of row in tableCell, depends how you are populating Values in TableView, Likewise if you having a dictionary used to populate tableView, Then on click of cell Just pass that, Or you can maintain separate arrays If required

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. `cellForRowAt` configures the cell and can do whatever it likes to that cell. You would use a custom UITableViewCell subclass for which you have declared a `o_1` instance property. Now, when your `cellForRowAt` sets the cell's label text for this row, it can also set the property of this cell.

Just keep in mind that cells are reusable. You must expect and allow the cell's `o_1` property to be changed by a later call to `cellForRowAt` when the cell is reused, probably at a different row, exactly as you expect to have happen with the label text.